# HTML - JavaScript - Spring Change row color depending upon the value

Tags: javascript, spring

I have variable being initialized by Spring Model and depending upon the value of a column, I need to display the relevant color of background.

I tried following JavaScript code but is not working:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var table = document.getElementById("dataStatusVar");    
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // add event handlers so rows light up and are clickable
    for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var value = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        if (value == 'mraible') {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    }           
-->
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <table id="dataStatusVar">
      <tr>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>START</th>
        <th>END</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>mraible</td>
        <td>startvalue</td>
        <td>endvalue</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expect the row to be RED. But it is not.

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the js console? try adding breakpoint at this line: if (value == 'mraible') {

Comment: I am not sure how to debug it. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

cant comment so asking in answers, have you tried writing the js code below html?
The JS needs to be executed after the html is loaded and using a separate file when dealing with JSTL can be weird to say the lease so the best option is to execute js code after the HTML and JSTL is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to choose the jstl here is the following code

> ```
> <c:forEach items="${rows}" var="usr" varStatus="st">  
>    <c:choose>  
>       <c:when test="${st.index%2 eq 0}">   
>          <c:set var="tr" value="red"></c:set>  
>       </c:when>   
>       <c:otherwise>  
>          <c:set var="tr" value="blue"></c:set>  
>       </c:otherwise>
>    </c:choose>
>    <div>
>      <table id="dataStatusVar">
>        <tr>
>          <th>TYPE</th>
>          <th>START</th>
>          <th>END</th>
>        </tr>  
>        <tr bgcolor="{tr}">  
>          <td>mraible</td>
>          <td>startvalue</td>
>          <td>endvalue</td>
>        </tr>
>      </table>
>    </div>
>  </c:forEach>
> ```

Comment: Swathi - This is not working. I tried the code but it is coming just BLACK. Also I need to modify color depending upon the value.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <table id="dataStatusVar">
      <tr>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>START</th>
        <th>END</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>mraible</td>
        <td>startvalue</td>
        <td>endvalue</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
    var table = document.getElementById("dataStatusVar");    
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");

// add event handlers so rows light up and are clickable
for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var tds = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (tds.length) {
        var value = tds[0].innerHTML;
        if (value == 'mraible') {
            rows[i].style.background = "red"; // for entire row
            //tds[0].style.background = "red"; // for a cell
        }
    }
}           
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a function/statements depend on DOM element(s), then measures has to be taken that during the execution of that function/statement element(s) should be available (loaded) for processing. So, i have called setColour() function once the elements are loaded (in body)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setColour()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("dataStatusVar"); //Gets the required table   
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //Gets the trs from the table

        for (i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {//For each row in the table
            var tdelements = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; //First cell in the selected row
            if (tdelements != null) { //If first cell exists
                var value = tdelements.innerHTML; //Fetch the content of the first cell in the selected row
                if (value === 'mraible') { //Checks if the cell has expected value
                    rows[i].style.background = "red"; // Sets red color for the entire row
                }
            }
        }           
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setColour()">
  <div>
    <table id="dataStatusVar">
      <tr>
        <th>TYPE</th>
        <th>START</th>
        <th>END</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>mraible</td>
        <td>startvalue</td>
        <td>endvalue</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>      
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From your sample, i have assumed that color has to be set for the entire row if the content of the the first column in the row matches a particular value.